# Is my R logistic regression model ok? (NOVICE)

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I'm currently training a model for spam detection on a training set with 4757 observations with 3000 variables counting word frequencies. It is taking forever and I have a deadline coming up so I wanted to just run the code by you guys to ensure I'm not waiting for nothing.

[image: R code for logistic regression model]

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need all 3000 words as variables? You can't trim them down?

Comment: I figured I would get a better model if I kept all of the variables. Maybe I could remove the words which occur in both spam and non-spam, leaving only words which occur in one or the other. Does that sound reasonable? I think that would leave about 500 remaining as there is a lot of overlap

Comment: If you remove the words that are in both, then you will be left with only-spam and only non-spam, so there is no point in doing a logistic regression - you will get a singular fit, with 100% probabilities. If anything, you could do a logistic regression on the overlapping words. With this type of set-up, I might be more inclined to just do a simple table of proportions or odds. If you see a particular word in an email, what are the odds that the e-mail is spammy? This takes much less computation, and is an easily interpretable result.

Comment: Can you [edit] to be specific about what in particular you want to know?

Comment: For a logistic regression with `n=4757`, `p=3000` I would suggest that you would be better off using a **penalized regression** via `glmnet` - there may be some more startup cost in figuring out how to use the machinery, but it will be better (and probably faster) in the long run.

Comment: As you have several hundred words restricted to one or the other class, your model presumably suffers from [perfect separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11109/28500) and its associated numerical problems. The suggestion from @BenBolker would overcome that; `glmnet` is evidently supported by `caret`. There's also a Firth penalization of logistic regression models implemented in the R [`logistf` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=logistf). I don't know if that's directly supported by `caret` but I understand that you can write your own methods to call that.

Comment: The name of the famous software is R not r! Edited ...